# Getting error on closing excel macro using vbscript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB

Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C: \Net_Zero_Final.xlsm",0,True)

ObjExcel.Visible = True

ObjExcel.Run "Net_Zero"

ObjExcel.application.quit ' <--- error here

Set ObjWB = Nothing

Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

[image: Error]

Getting error on the BOLD Part
Can anyone please suggest. tried everything to fix this.

Comment: It needs to be `ObjExcel.Quit`.

Comment: As @VBasic2008 says `Application` from VBA equivalent in VBScript is the `Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` call. There is no `ObjExcel.Application` as `ObjExcel` is `Application` so use `ObjExcel.Quit`.

Comment: ObjExcel.Quit tried this but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run a VBA Macro from a .vbs file (or any other location).

I tested the following code inside `test.vbs`.

```
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TestMacro2.xlsm", False, False)

ObjExcel.Visible = True

ObjExcel.Application.Run "TestMacro2.xlsm!TheMacro"

ObjWB.Close

Set ObjWB= Nothing

Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Where the macro inside the Excel file `TestMacro2.xlsm` was pretty simple

```
Sub TheMacro()
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

It worked without any problems.

Notice that instead of trying to close Excel application (`ObjExcel.Application.Quit`), I just close the opened Workbook (`ObjWB.Close`). This will avoid the script to close Excel while the user is working in another project.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB

Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C: \Net_Zero_Final.xlsm",0,True)

ObjExcel.Visible = True

ObjExcel.Run "Net_Zero"

ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

ObjWB.Close = False

ObjExcel.quit

Set ObjWB = Nothing

Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

It worked like this, I just passed ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

it won't display any alerts and it will simply close the excel without saving it.

i hope this is right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).